# Servlet filters and response wrapper

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

Trying to mess around with the response content I tried [this filter tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000578)

So I defined my classes as

```
public class FilterServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream
{
    //=======================================================================
    private DataOutputStream stream; 
    //=======================================================================
    public FilterServletOutputStream(OutputStream output) { 
      stream = new DataOutputStream(output); 
    }
    //=======================================================================
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException  {
        stream.write(b); 
    }
    //=======================================================================
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException  { 
        stream.write(b); 
    }
    //=======================================================================
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException  {
        stream.write(b,off,len); 
    }
    //=======================================================================
}




public class GenericResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper 
{ 
  private ByteArrayOutputStream output;
  private int contentLength;
  private String contentType;
  public GenericResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) { 
    super(response);
    output=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  } 
  public byte[] getData() { 
    return output.toByteArray(); 
  } 
  @Override
  public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() 
  { 
    return new FilterServletOutputStream(output); 
  } 

  @Override
  public PrintWriter getWriter() 
  { 
    return new PrintWriter(getOutputStream(),true); 
  } 

  @Override
  public void setContentLength(int length) { 
    this.contentLength = length;
    super.setContentLength(length); 
  } 

  public int getContentLength() { 
    return contentLength; 
  } 
  @Override
  public void setContentType(String type) { 
    this.contentType = type;
    super.setContentType(type); 
  } 
  @Override
  public String getContentType() { 
    return contentType; 
  } 
}
```

And then my filter.

```
public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain   chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    //===================================================================
    GenericResponseWrapper wrapper = new GenericResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
    chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(wrapper.getData());
    out.write("test content".getBytes());
    out.close();
    //===================================================================
}
```

The filter seems to be ok. I can read "test content" but it seems `wrapper.getData()` returns 0 bytes. When I call `chain.doFilter(..)` usually is a servlet that some times dispatches to a jsp page. Tried a URL of a JSP plain page but it does not seem to write data.
The filter is configured to catch ALL requests and it does it well.

What can I be doing so wrong? The only difference is that I added `@override`. But I tried without them also.

Added a JSP.

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style>
  <%-- @include file="/static/css/divs.css" --%>
  <%-- @include file="/static/css/links.css" --%>
  </style>
  <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px">
  <%--@include file="publicheader.jsp" --%>
  <div class="desktopwebpagecontainer">
  main page.
  </div>
  <%--@include file="publicfooter.jsp" --%>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: How can you tell that `wrapper.getData()` returns 0 bytes?

Comment: I can't thats why i say "it seems". What I can tell is that is not null.

Comment: Print out `getData().length`.

Comment: I printed to the console. It is 0. Failed to print it to the response before.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Show us a `Servlet` that would reproduce this. Make the example as minimal as possible.

Comment: It does the same no matters if it is a servlet or or a "Hello World" JSP page. So it doesnt make sense that is a servlet.

Comment: A JSP is a `Servlet`.

Comment: I know. It is. But as far as i can see i commented out everything that could be disturbing but still nothing. The JSP file is named "homeD.jsp and is intended to by destination of dispatch of a servlet maped at "/".

Comment: Ok, forget about the JSP completely, it is irrelevant. Your Servlet's handler method can simply do `response.getOutputStream().write(new byte[] {1,2,3,4});`.

Comment: By the way. The app is runing on Tomcat on Ubuntu 12.04. I got this version of Tomcat within the last 7 months.

Comment: Well. This is now the situation I tried response.getOutputStream().write(new byte[] {65,66,67,68}); and response.getOutputStream().print("In servlet"); And was included in the output. The problem seems to arise in JSP files. I suspect that JSP use some other "getoutputstream" method that I did not catch in my wrapper.

Comment: The `ServletResponse` interface only provides `getOutputStream` and `getWriter`.

Comment: I don't want to keep guessing anymore. Please give us a complete, reproducible example that gives unexpected results and explain it.

Comment: Now. And misteriously seems to work everything fine. If i find out what was the cause I will post a comment about this. Thanks for your help. The "response.getOutputStream().write(new byte[] {1,2,3,4});" was a lead in the first place.

Comment: Sotirios: I am not sure but it was fixed by making PrintWriter and OutputStreams fields. Then return them instead of creating "new" every time getOutputStream() and getWriter(). Best regards.

Comment: I'm happy it all worked out. Consider adding your solution and explaining it or deleting the question if you don't think it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What fixed the issue was this making pwriter and outpstrm class members (fields).

```
private PrintWriter pwriter = null;
private ServletOutputStream outpstrm = null;
```

And then changin the methods for geting them

```
@Override
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() 
{ 
    if (outpstrm == null) outpstrm = new AppServletOutputStream(output);
    return outpstrm;
} 
@Override
public PrintWriter getWriter() 
{ 
    if (pwriter == null) pwriter = new PrintWriter(getOutputStream(),true); 
    return pwriter;
}
```

This seems to be what fixed my problem. Since this change the wrapper worked fine.
By the way. Who said that you can't call the method forward(req, res) method of the RequestDispatcher class?.

Comment: Is `AppServletOutputStream` same as `FilterServletOutputStream`. Secondly I couldn't get `request.getRequestDispatcher("abcd.html").forward(request, response);` working. I added `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>` in my filter mapping so the filter gets called during forward as well but somehow the modified response is not going to the browser. Browser still shows abcd.html as it is in the html file.